# Azure Datalake Gen2 Rename File Issue

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, azure-sdk-python

**Describe the bug:**
Utilizing the DataLakeServiceClient, I am trying to rename files after they have been unzip in Azure Synapse notebooks, but I have been successful up until the point of renaming (code is failing at the last line for rename_file method).

**I receive the following error:**
HttpResponseError: (OutOfRangeInput) The specified resource name length is not within the permissible limits.
RequestId:6ef9e79f-a01f-0067-5cb0-62b105000000
Time:2023-03-30T02:34:49.8798540Z
Code: OutOfRangeInput
Message: The specified resource name length is not within the permissible limits.
RequestId:6ef9e79f-a01f-0067-5cb0-62b105000000
Time:2023-03-30T02:34:49.8798540Z

```
    extraction_path = f"/synfs/{mssparkutils.env.getJobId()}/sink/{self.sink_path}"
    with zipfile.ZipFile(compressed_data) as zip_file:
        zip_file.extractall(extraction_path)

    dl_service_client_source = DataLakeServiceClient(f"https://{lake}.dfs.core.windows.net", credential=credential)
    dl_file_system_client_source = dl_service_client_source.get_file_system_client("refined")
    dl_directory_client_source = dl_file_system_client_source.get_file_client(self.solution_folder) 

    files1 = (self.solution_folder + '/' + self.sink_path)

    files = dl_file_system_client_source.get_paths(path=files1)

    for file in files:
        if not file.is_directory:
            file_client = dl_file_system_client_source.get_file_client(file.name)
            dir_path, file_name1 = os.path.split(file.name)
            file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file.name)
            new_name = 'test'
            new_file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, new_name)
            file_client.rename_file(new_file_path)
```

**All of my values are printing out correctly, but I am still receiving the length error.

Output of the values:**

**file_name:** IT/SpatioTemporalAssetCatalog/0_unzipped/1511111156_DodgeDeploy/Manufacturing/ORTHOMOSAIC/TKC/gmwc/TKC_Orthomosaic_export_TueAug31183858312496

**files.name:** IT/SpatioTemporalAssetCatalog/0_unzipped/1511111156_DodgeDeploy/Manufacturing/ORTHOMOSAIC/TKC/gmwc/TKC_Orthomosaic_export_TueAug31183858312496.kml

**new_name:** test

**new_file_path:** IT/SpatioTemporalAssetCatalog/0_unzipped/1511111156_DodgeDeploy/Manufacturing/ORTHOMOSAIC/TKC/gmwc/test

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the complete path in your *file_name*, The name of the container **IT** (just 2 characters and in UPPER case) is the cause of the issue here.

The container name, may only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens, and must begin with a letter or a number. Each hyphen must be preceded and followed by a non-hyphen character. The container name must be between 3 and 63 characters long. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-containers-portal). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. How can I address this issue? the container name has been “IT” for a while now

Comment: Also, how would they be able to create that container name if it’s not allowed or per documentation request would fail?